# What do Maxell's "XLII-S "and "MX" stand for?

Tags: abbreviations

Does anybody know what Maxell's ["XLII-S "and "MX"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxell) stand for?

> During the height of the Compact Audio Cassette's popularity, Maxell's audio cassettes were held in high regard, producing some of the finest examples of the standard available. The performance of the XLII-S (CrO2) and MX (pure metal particles) cassettes was highly regarded in the pre-digital domestic recording medium.

Comment: Why do you believe they have to "stand for" anything?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can find, the XLII-S means "Type II Super Fine Epitaxial" and MX means "Metaxial".

Note the text written out on the cassettes:

[image]
[image]

Breaking it down, XL refers to their Epitaxial line of cassettes. You might also see UDXL (the UD referring to Ultra Dynamic). You then have either a Roman Numeral I or II for Type I (Normal bias) or Type II (High bias). The S then refers to Super Fine - finer (that is, smaller) magnetic particles than the non-S range.

The MX then stands for Metaxial; again, as in the picture below:

[image]

As you can see, these Metaxial cassettes are Type IV.

Answer (score 0):

The likely aren't initialisms, but they may 'represent' something. There are only about 120 words in the English language that begin with 'X' and none of them commonly used in everyday speech. When you see the letter X used, it is rarely to represent one of these.

The letter 'X' is sometimes used to substitue for the word 'cross' or words that sound like it - for example, 'Christmas' is sometimes abbreviated to 'Xmas'). Most commonly though, 'X' is used to represent the word "*extra*" (meaning 'more'). For example, in clothes sizes, 'XL' means "extra large", and 'XXL' means "extra, extra large".

However, "XL" is sometimes used as a phonetic representation of the world "excel" (meaning 'to be superior'). In your example of cassettes, I suspect the use of 'XL' is to imply superior quality. It is unlkely to refer to size, as the cassette case wouldn't be a standard size and the length of the tape measured by the running time (60, 90, 120 etc).

'MX' is used to represent a number of things - for example, as an abbreviation of the sport of 'Motorcross' (M for Motor, X to represent 'cross' as mentioned above). However, it is often used to imply the word "*maximum*" (the most).

In your example I suspect the use of 'MX' is either to imply 'maximum', or possibly, as you linked it to metal particles, the 'M' stands for 'metal' and the 'X' to imply this is something extra. Alternatively, as the manufacturer's name is 'Maxell', it could just be representative of that.

There are other uses of these letters - 'X' can suggest that something is "experimental". It can also be used to represent something deliberately unnamed (eg "Mr X" or "Brand X"). Context is everything.

Comment: So very sorry for the late reply! Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations !